# .DLL:How to modify a Dynamic Link Library (.dll) file?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, dll, windows-8

I have been able to open a Windows 8 shsxs.dll file in Visual Studio 2010.

**But it's write protected.**

Now, while in Visual Studio, **I want to know how to modify an existing image or add a new image in 
png format to shsxs.dll**.

Also, I have been a to unpack/extract it too using 7-zip.

Thus, how can I repack the unpacked .dll file back to a .dll file?

*PS: I'm new to Visual Studio, so question or tag may seem irrelevant. Please correct me & help me out asap.*

Comment: What does "it's write protected" mean?

Comment: As I mentioned, shsxs.dll is a Windows 8 system32 file. Thus, when I open images in it in VS2010, it doesn't allow me to modify them, nor can I add a new image in PNG format to it. It only allows me to add a image in BMP format only.

Comment: Sure it is write protected, it implements the Start menu in Win8.  Don't mess with system files.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sir, in order to learn, i have to tweak & take risks. :)
So, can you help me how to remove the write-protection?
Also, I'm doing all changes on a copy of the file with backup of original in place.

Comment: I would suggest you start by learning with recommended engineering techniques. Once you understand those, you can expand to the non-recommended techniques.

Comment: Are you trying to edit it in situ, in the system32 directory?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:No-no... not at all...
I'm working on a copy of it, in the differnet OS altogether... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface:** I haven't got a chance to work with Windows 8 yet, so the information in this answer might be slightly off. Or completely useless.

I think by **write protected** you mean **read-only**. That's easily corrected. Locate your `shsxs.dll` and right-click on it. Select *Properties* and uncheck the *Read-Only* checkbox in the *Attributes* section, *if* it is checked. Then go to the *Security* tab, and click edit. Select your username (or the user *Everyone* if it's there) and tick the *Full access* checkbox in the *Allow* column. Click OK. Click OK again.

Next you want to know how to **modify an existing image** or **add a new image in png format**. These are two different things.

### Let's tackle the **modifying** first.

You can't do that with 7-Zip. You can only use it to look at the DLL's content, but you can't modify it. You need a specialized tool for the job, I recommend the [XN Resource Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xn-resource-editor/), which is basically a better [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), which used to be *the* program to edit already compiled resources. I'm not sure whether they work with Windows 8 modules, though. If they don't, please link to an alternative which can in the comments, or edit this answer if you can.

After you install the XN Resource Editor, start it, and open your `shsxs.dll`. On the left side you have the resource tree. Expand the *Bitmap* subtree. You should see a bunch of numbers, each one represents one resource in the DLL. Expand each subtree until you find the desired image.

Once you find your image, you can modify it inline using XN Resource Editor's built-in picture editor. You can also remember the resource's number, right-click on the Image and select *Delete Resource*, then go to the *Resource* menu and select *Import Image Resource*, find your desired image. Then right-click on the newly imported image in XN Resource Editor, select *Properties* and  enter the old resource's number (you remembered it, right?) and press OK.

### Adding a new Image is not that different.

It's easy, simply go to the *Resource* menu and select *Import Image Resource*, find your desired image and click OK. **DONE**.

---

*Edit:* Since the file came from System32, I added instructions on how to grant the user full access to the file, additionally to removing the read-only flag.

Comment: It appears that the link at `http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm` is dead/ returning blank page, can you search for a replacement url, or use the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330163928/http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) for an archieved version?

Comment: That link is dead - it can be downloaded on sourceforge.net https://sourceforge.net/projects/xn-resource-editor/